# Add Audio Delay on outgoing WebRTC call

Tags: node.js, webrtc, html5-audio, audiocontext

I'm creating an Electron app, and I want to intentially add a delay to the outgoing audio (Up to 10 seconds) in a webrtc call to simulate audio lagg.

I have tried using playoutDelayHint with WebRTC but it's very inconsistent. I want to be able to control the time delay very precisely.

```
audioReceiver.playoutDelayHint = 1;
audioReceiver.jitterBufferDelayHint = 1;
```

I have also tried using the AudioDelay node but it's not working, no delay at all.

```
let audioContext = new AudioContext();
let audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(canvasStream);
let audioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

let delay = audioContext.createDelay(3)
delay.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

**Are there any other options or ways to make the options above work?**

Comment: I think this can be done using insertable streams: https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-encoded-transform/blob/main/explainer.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to apply the audio delay to the incoming stream.
Not optimal but it works.

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

let audioDelay = audioContext.createDelay(10); // 10 seconds max delay
audioDelay.delayTime.value = 3 // Seconds delay

source.connect(audioDelay).connect(audioContext.destination)
```